# How to globally disable git hooks

Tags: git, security, githooks

For security reasons I would like git hooks to be disabled by default.

More specifically, when I run a git command in any git repository on my (Kubuntu) OS account, no git hooks should be executed, unless somehow specified.

In run all my code in Vagrant or Docker and the attack I want to avoid is the one where malicious code in the VM writes to the git hooks directory and thus gets itself onto the host machine. Disabling git hooks by default is a line of defense against this.

I'm looking for a solution that does not require per repository work and state. In my search I ran into [this script](https://gist.github.com/MrSwed/4bb4e0a8c2a2f35827e6d9b410642582) which breaks both those requirements.

Ideally there is a simple solution such as putting this in `.bash_aliases`:

```
alias git='/usr/bin/git --no-hooks'
```

Comment: Leave the responsability of using hooks to your user. They are installing such hooks. The git hook directory that matters is those on the `git` *client* (not host) machine. In other words, by definition, git hooks are *always* "specified" and explicitly installed.

Comment: Otherwise [git](http://git-scm.com/) is free software, so you could patch and fork it to add such a `--no-hooks` option, but you don't need it. I don't understand why you think there is some *additional* security risk, since git hooks run on the client machine

Comment: Leave it to "my user"? I think you misunderstood something because your comment makes no sense to me. I am talking about git on my machine.

Comment: Then improve your question to explain more. Give some [MCVE] with *real* `git` commands showing the vulnerability; I don't understand whatr security risk do you percieve. Show an actual case (you could even make some free software example on [github](http://github.com/)). In general, `git` is used in a client-server setting (e.g. `git pull`). Otherwise, take advantage that `git` is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) so study its source code and improve it for your needs

Comment: The source code of `git` is on https://github.com/git/git ; you can fork it and improve it for your needs. IMHO you don't need any improvement (but I tend to believe you don't know `git` well enough; and neither do I). As I said, hooks are run on git client side. They don't give any *additional* security risk. Of course, on that client side, the user will also run arbitrary commands (since he is building software).

Comment: The hooks directory is under `.git/hooks` (on client machine) and is *not* manageable by `git` commands. If you need hooks, you need to *explicitly* install them there. Once you are able to install scripts on a machine, you already have a giant (infinite) security hole. So your patch won't improve any security

Comment: For example my [melt-monitor-2015](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor) github project needs hooks, and I have to *explicitly* provide code installing them (in the `Makefile`). You cannot, thu these hooks -even if you overwrite them to get malicious hooks-, gain priviledge on `github` servers. These hooks are running on the *client* machine (the Linux desktop on which I `git clone` that repository)

Comment: You need to understand that `git` is a [distributed version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control) system. Disabling hooks won't improve any security (but simply annoy your users). Think of `git` in client/server terms and in protocol terms

Comment: I am aware of the things you pointed out. The vulnerability does not come from cloning repos with hooks in them (the hooks won't be cloned) or from just running git commands. It comes from malicious code in a VM creating git hooks on the host machine, which it can if the project directory is mounted. Thus it gets arbitrary code execution on the host as soon as you execute a git command. This is what I described already.

Comment: You should improve your question to give a real example as some [MCVE]. Without any example, your question is unclear. And please don't comment it, but **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: If you are not familiar enough with what I am talking about to understand the question I doubt you can answer it. I appreciate you trying to be helpful but this is not how I am perceiving this conversation.

Comment: Notice that I did not answer your question. However, without any [MCVE] it has no much sense (and you've got no answers so far). It might get eventually closed.

Answer (score 11):

Setting [core.hooksPath](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corehooksPath) in `$HOME/.gitconfig` seems to work for me

```
[core]
    hooksPath = $SOME_DIR_WITHOUT_HOOKS
```

To enable hooks for a specific repo, you can probably reset it in `$REPO/.git/config`

```
[core]
    hooksPath = $GIT_DIR/hooks
```

Answer (score 4):

The hooks are not the only way an attacker with write access to the `.git` directory can attack the user of the `.git` directory, the option `diff.external` can for example be set to execute anything, and who keeps track of all new Git features?

Even letting the attacker have write access to repository may be bad, if your development environment looks for configuration files within, or if it has some script that is executed locally.

Protecting `.git` is still a good idea, I propose these solutions:

- Make `.git` read-only in the virtual machine.
- Place the `.git` directory outside the working directory shared with the virtual machines.  The `--git-dir` flag or the `GIT_DIR` environment variable controls where Git looks for the `.git` directory.  Has the drawback that the `.git` directory is not shared with the virtual machine if it needs it, and that the command line flag or the environment variable will need to be set before working with each different repository.